# How to make Cmake find tesseract library in Windows (Findtesseract.cmake)?

Tags: windows, dll, cmake, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I installed, in Windows, Tesseract, using "Windows Installer made with MinGW-w64 from UB Mannheim" from [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/4.0-with-LSTM.html#400-alpha-for-windows), and added to my CMakeLists.txt:

find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)

but I get

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTesseract.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Tesseract", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Tesseract"
  (requested version 4.0) with any of the following names:

    TesseractConfig.cmake
    tesseract-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Tesseract" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Tesseract_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Tesseract" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I tried adding

```
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Users\\LZ\\Downloads\\tesseract-4.0.0-alpha")
```

but it doesn't help. And also in this installation folder there are no `TesseractConfig.cmake` or `tesseract-config.cmake`

Comment: It should be `TesseractConfig.cmake` file under `cmake/` subdirectory. In that case setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should work. (But when set this variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` script, it is better to use "/" as a path separator.) If you don't have `TesseractConfig.cmake` file, then your installation is too old. You may try to install Tesseract from sources. Otherwise, you need to get `FindTesseract.cmake` script somewhere and set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` accordingly. Note, that setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is still needed in this case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev there's no cmake folder on the installation folder. And it's the version 4.0.0 which uses cmake. Did you have sucess with tesseract and cmake? Know where I can find an installed? I didn't want to compile from source because many deps will be required.

Comment: Strange, 4.0 version [should install](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/4.0/CMakeLists.txt#L445) `TesseractConfig.cmake` file. No, I don't know other installers for tesseract and haven't used it.