# How to use Tesseract OCR with Cmake on Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, cmake, shared-libraries, tesseract

I'm tryint to use tesseract in my cmake project on Windows. I installed tesseract 5.0 and tesseract 4.0. They both come with no cmake folder so the line

```
find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)
```

produces

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTesseract.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Tesseract", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Tesseract"
  (requested version 4.0) with any of the following names:

    TesseractConfig.cmake
    tesseract-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Tesseract" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Tesseract_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Tesseract" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

However, in the installation folder for tesseract 5.0, there's `libtesseract-5.dll` and many others. Can I link those in my cmake project? If so, how? And why there are no include files in the installation folder? How am I suppose to include the .h files in my project?

Comment: How did you installed tesseract?

Comment: "*They both come with no cmake folder*"... This is odd. The GitHub [repo](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) shows there should be a `cmake` folder. How did you install tesseract?

Comment: I guess this question is just a continuation of the previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426500/how-to-make-cmake-find-tesseract-library-in-windows-findtesseract-cmake) asked be the same author. And I wonder whether these both questions are actually about the **same problem**.

Comment: @user898678  I installed through here: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki the version 5.0.0 which does not come with cmake and also through here https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/4.0-with-LSTM.html#400-alpha-for-windows in "Windows Installer made with MinGW-w64 from UB Mannheim" which also does not come with cmake

Comment: @squareskittles there's a cmake folder in the repo, but I think it's for compiling the project with cmake, it's not the folder that is placed into the installation folder

Comment: Can you show your *CMakeLists.txt* (at least the parts that reference *Tesseract*)?

Comment: @CristiFati it's just a minimum cmake with `find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)`, just to see if it'll find them

Comment: Ok, then the question doesn't make too much sense. There are alternative ways for *find\_package* (you'll still have to build *Tesseract*), but you'll need to provide a specific usecase.

Answer (score 0):

UB-Mannheim installer is autotools build and it has only runtime part of tesseract (e.g. executables and linked libraries).
You can not use it for any development because it does not provide needed files (libraries and header files), so missing cmake files are reasonable consequences of this installation.
You can check this information in detail where installer finished.

Comment: So how can I use tesseract in cmake on windows?

Comment: you have to build it from source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the MSYS/Mingw build of tesseract: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-tesseract-ocr`? Since there is no cmake config file you will have to use pkg_check_modules instead (see also [cMakefile for using tesseract and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994135/cmakefile-for-using-tesseract-and-opencv/51059723) without the opencv bit)